# merge sort code in python not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, mergesort

### Merge sort code in python

List index out of range error is flashing every time I try to run it.
Don't know whats going on exactly.I'm pretty much new to python and algorithm stuff. Please help me to debug it.

```
def merge(m_list,first,middle,last):
    m_first = []
    m_last = []
    for each in range(first,middle):
        m_first.append(m_list[each])

    for each in range(middle,last+1):
        m_last.append(m_list[each])

    i=0
    j=0
    k=0

    while(i<middle and j<last-middle+1):
        if(m_first[i]<m_last[j]):
            m_list[k] = m_first[i]

            i +=1
        else:
            m_list[k] = m_last[j]

            j +=1
        k +=1

    print(m_list)

    while(i<middle):
        m_list[k] = m_first[i]
        k +=1
        i +=1

    while(j<last-middle+1):
        m_list[k] = m_last[j]
        k +=1
        j +=1

def merge_sort(m_list,first,last):
    if(first<last):
        middle = int(abs((first+last)/2))
        merge_sort(m_list,first,middle)
        merge_sort(m_list,middle+1,last)
        merge(m_list,first,middle,last)

    return(m_list)



merge_sort([1,4,6,2,3,5],0,5)
```

> Here is the error shown by the code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "merge_sort.py", line 48, in <module>
    merge_sort([1,4,6,2,3,5],0,5)
  File "merge_sort.py", line 41, in merge_sort
    merge_sort(m_list,middle+1,last)
  File "merge_sort.py", line 40, in merge_sort
    merge_sort(m_list,first,middle)
  File "merge_sort.py", line 42, in merge_sort
    merge(m_list,first,middle,last)
  File "merge_sort.py", line 15, in merge
    if(m_first[i]<m_last[j]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please include a complete error message. And where does `k` change? Is it always equal to 0?

Comment: Incremented the value of k as well still not working

Comment: try to understand what the error means first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed few things. Incrementing `k`, initializing `k` and setting proper boundaries for conditions. 
Below is the working code. Compare it with yours and see what you have missed.

```
def merge(m_list,first,middle,last):
    m_first = []
    m_last = []
    for each in range(first,middle+1):
        m_first.append(m_list[each])

    for each in range(middle+1,last+1):
        m_last.append(m_list[each])

    i=0
    j=0
    k=first

    while(i<middle-first +1 and j<last-middle):
        if(m_first[i]<m_last[j]):
            m_list[k] = m_first[i]
            k +=1
            i +=1
        else:
            m_list[k] = m_last[j]
            k +=1
            j +=1

     print(m_list)

    while(i<middle-first +1):
        m_list[k] = m_first[i]
        k +=1
        i +=1

    while(j<last-middle):
        m_list[k] = m_last[j]
        k +=1
        j +=1

def merge_sort(m_list,first,last):
    if(first<last):
        middle = int(abs((first+last)/2))
        merge_sort(m_list,first,middle)
        merge_sort(m_list,middle+1,last)
        merge(m_list,first,middle,last)

    return(m_list)



print merge_sort([9,7,6,5,4,3],0,5)
```